# Java stack not following LIFO

Tags: java, data-structures, functional-programming, stack

Why is my java stack not following the principle of LIFO while printing?

```
import java.util.*;

class StackTrace
{
    public static void main(String []ar)
    {

    Stack myStack = new Stack();
    myStack.push(1);
    myStack.push(2);
    myStack.push(3);
    myStack.push(4);

    System.out.println(myStack);

    Object Arr[]=myStack.toArray();
    for(Object a:Arr)
        System.out.println(a); 
    }
}
```

Output :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]


1
2
3
4
```

In the above code, the statement  `System.out.println(myStack);` is printing data sequentially rather than last in first out manner.

Why so?

And also how is the `toArray()` method working in the above program?

Comment: Last in, first _out_. You didn't take anything out.

Comment: Printing is not same as getting elements from stack. Try using `pop` until stack is empty: `while(!myStack.empty()) System.out.println(myStack.pop());`

Comment: Yeah, you can pop the Stack, but the real problem is that Stack inherits from Vector.

Answer (score 1):

toArray method will return the array of elements in the order they were inserted to stack.
If you need the elements in LIFO use the pop method.
You can go through Stack api here,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Answer (score 1):

I'll start off by saying that, like you, this annoyed me. A stack in it's most primal sense isn't able to access elements other than the top element. As far as I can tell, the only logic behind this is that java is treating this the way it is stored.

As for the storage of a Stack in Java, it stores in much the same way as an ArrayList (using an array, doubling when it fills). Similarly, the toString of Stack comes from Vector (similar to an ArrayList), which starts at the beginning. Since the "top" of the stack is the end, it gets outputted last.

Here's some example code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class StacksTesting
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            st.add(i);
        System.out.println(st);   
        while(!st.isEmpty())
           System.out.print(st.pop()+" ");
    }
}
```

Will give:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

as output

Answer (score 0):

> **Q:** Why is my java-stack not following the principle of LIFO while printing?

The class `Stack` is an extension of the class `Vector` that can be found in `java.util.*;`.

Using the class `Stack` included in the Java API is *not* a good way to implement a `Stack` in Java.

The class `Vector` has become [obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated).  Saying that a `Stack` *is a* `Vector` breaks the OOP principle of encapsulation.  You only want to be able to access the top of the `Stack`.  However, because your `Stack` *is a* `Vector`, it inherits undesirable methods from the class `Vector`.

See Oracle's Java documentation here:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

So you can call the `Vector` methods, in addition to the `Stack` methods of `peek()`, `pop()`, `push()` and `empty()`.  This will allow you to access more than just the top of the `Stack`, or print the entire `Stack`.

To fix this, you have to write your own `Stack` class.  You can try implementing your `Stack` as an `Array`, a `LinkedList`, a `Deque` or using a `List` interface.